# rpm for static version of ACE/TAO

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm, ace, tao

I need ACE/TAO framework for building my applications.

I found the RPM to install those at this page.

http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/libraries:/ACE:/micro:/versioned/RedHat_RHEL-6/x86_64/

These do install the SHARED libraries of that framework.

Unfortunately I was not able to find the STATIC libraries of ACE/TAO and those are the ones I need.

Have any of you come up or found some rpm for the static libraries?

I really would like to avoid using `MPC` that is the main build tool of that framework.

I am using Red-Hat Enterprise 6.3

Comment: There is currently no rpm for static libraries of ACE/TAO. That probably needs some work to create, see http://www.theaceorb.nl, that is the company I work for and for which I created the RPM spec file that is currently used on OBS

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. I found that (need to tested) by using the string 'sharedname' it should be able to produce static version of the library. Few days ago I used rpmbuild to rebuild all shared library safely from the source as it is. I am going to try this approach and let you knwo.

Comment: Great, let me know the results, maybe direct by email, my email address is in the ChangeLog of ACE